# How to pass matlab::data::TypedArray<double> as pointer to construct Armadillo matrix in MATLAB mex file?

Tags: c++, matlab, mex, armadillo

Could someone with more experience advise me how to achieve the above point please?

This must be certainly a trivial matter; however, after many days and nights of trying, researching and reading up on internet I still cannot my head around it.

**Setup:**

Two C++ source files and a header file:

**main.cpp**

- contains the general IO interface between MATLAB and C++
- feeds two double arrays (dimensions for each: ncols: 168, and nrows: 2) and two double const doubles into C++
- it does some Armadillo based looping (this part is not that important therefore omitted) by calling *foo()*
- returns *outp* which is a “just a plain” scalar double
- Nothing fancy or complicated.

**sub.cpp**

- This is only for the *foo()* looping part.
- The problem is that the two **arma::mat mY** and **arma::mat mD** matrices do not get properly populated somehow using the pointer to auxiliary memory as explained at the below armadillo documentation.
- http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#adv_constructors_mat

**sub.hpp**

- Just a simple header file.

I would be very grateful for any help, hints or constructive comments in advance.

```
// main.cpp
// MATLAB API Header Files
#include "mex.hpp"
#include "mexAdapter.hpp"

// Custom header
#include "sub.hpp"

// Overloading the function call operator, thus class acts as a functor
class MexFunction : public matlab::mex::Function {
    public:
        void operator()(matlab::mex::ArgumentList outputs,
                        matlab::mex::ArgumentList inputs){
            
            matlab::data::ArrayFactory factory;
            // Validate arguments
            checkArguments(outputs, inputs);

            double* darrY = matlab::data::TypedArray<double>(std::move(inputs[0])).release().get();
            double* darrD = matlab::data::TypedArray<double>(std::move(inputs[1])).release().get();
            const double csT = inputs[2][0];
            const double csKy = inputs[3][0];

            // data type of outp is "just" a plain double, NOT a double array
            double outp = foo(darrY, darrD, csT, csKy);

            outputs[0] = factory.createScalar(outp);

            void checkArguments(matlab::mex::ArgumentList outputs, matlab::mex::ArgumentList inputs){
            // Create pointer to MATLAB engine
            std::shared_ptr<matlab::engine::MATLABEngine> matlabPtr = getEngine();
            // Create array factory, allows us to create MATLAB arrays in C++
            matlab::data::ArrayFactory factory;
            // Check input size and types
            if (inputs[0].getType() != ArrayType::DOUBLE ||
                inputs[0].getType() == ArrayType::COMPLEX_DOUBLE)
            {
                // Throw error directly into MATLAB if type does not match
                matlabPtr->feval(u"error", 0,
                    std::vector<Array>({ factory.createScalar("Input must be double array.") }));
            }
            // Check output size
            if (outputs.size() > 1) {
                matlabPtr->feval(u"error", 0, 
                    std::vector<Array>({ factory.createScalar("Only one output is returned.") }));
                }
        }
};

// sub.cpp

#include "sub.hpp"
#include "armadillo"

double foo(double dY[], double dD[], const double T, const double Ky) {
    
    double sum = 0;

    // Conversion of inputs parameters to armadillo matrices using the armadillo's so called advanced matrix constructor:
    // mat(ptr_aux_mem, n_rows, n_cols, copy_aux_mem = true, strict = false)
    // Fixme: parameterize n_rows, n_colss
    arma::mat mY(&dY[0], 2, 168, false);
    arma::mat mD(&dD[0], 2, 168, false);

    // Armadillo calculations

    for(int t=0; t<int(T); t++){

        // some armadillo based calculation
        // each for cycle increments sum by its return value 
    }

    return sum;
}

// sub.hpp

#ifndef SUB_H_INCLUDED
#define SUB_H_INCLUDED

double foo(double dY[], double dD[], const double T, const double Ky);

#endif // SUB_H_INCLUDED
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a similar question at [MATLAB Central](https://se.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/436916-how-to-access-raw-data-via-the-mex-c-api#). Changing the lines

```
double* darrY = matlab::data::TypedArray<double>(std::move(inputs[0])).release().get();
double* darrD = matlab::data::TypedArray<double>(std::move(inputs[1])).release().get();
```

to

```
TypedArray<double> matrix1 = std::move(inputs[0]);
TypedArray<double> matrix2 = std::move(inputs[1]);
buffer_ptr_t<double> Y = matrix1.release();
buffer_ptr_t<double> D = matrix2.release();
double* darrY = Y.get();
double* darrD = D.get();
```

seems to solve the problem. When I debugged your code it looked like both matrices got the same address for some reason.

Comment: @RolenClaes thanks you for your answer which looks promising! I am going to check it asap, and if it works (which is highly like the case) then I’ll accept yours as the correct answer. (Sorry for changing to order of first/last names after @ sign. SO does not allow it otherwise...)
Do you use Intel MKL for compiling the mex file with Armadillo, or do you compile with the OpenBLAS (or other linear algebra package) static/dynamic libraries shipped with Armadillo? The reason of asking is because debugging is very fragile with OpenBLAS. (I attach Visual Studio Code to the running MATLAB process.)

Comment: Great that it worked, I have compiled Armadillo "from scratch" using Intel MKL. There is also an alternative solution in the referred link provided by Savyasachi Singh.

Comment: @RolenClaes thanks for your answer anew. How could you compile the mex file with Armadillo, please? By compiling "from scratch", do you mean without using MATLAB's mex command?  The reason why I am asking that I've used the mex command so far but I could not yet have it compiled using Intel MKL static/dynamic links even though I tried to do everything "by the book" = using Intel® oneAPI MKL Link Line Advisor. That's why I had to resort to OpenBLAS. I presume there is a more elegant way of compiling mex files with Armadillo which are suitable for interfacing with MATLAB.

Comment: I compiled Armadillo with the provided CMake (using MKL) and installed the 'libarmadillo.so' file. Mex compiling in Matlab by "mex CFLAGS='$CFLAGS -ggdb -O0 -larmadillo' myMex.cpp", I am using Ubuntu 20.04, Matlab 2020b and Armadillo 9.700.2

Comment: @RolenClaes I appreciate your detailed answer. Thank you! Oh, well. I am using Windows 10 with the minGW64 compiler. I have also adjusted the Armadillo config headers, but I am still missing something. I guess on Ubuntu (Linux in general), it is more straightforward to get the mex compilation properly done with Intel MKL, or maybe just for me.

Comment: @RolenClaes How is it possible to dynamically parametrize the rows and cols dimensions of armadillo matrices to avoid hard coding of values with this current setup? Actually, I've just posted another SO question on this topic. I am pretty sure that you know it, which I would highly appreciate.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65868123/dynamic-parameterization-of-armadillo-matrix-dimensions-in-c